# Why the sum of these fractions is the sum of the divisors of 12 divided by 12?

Tags: arithmetic, fractions, pattern-recognition

\begin{align*}\frac11+\frac12+\frac13 +\frac14+ \frac16+\frac{1}{12}\\=\frac{12}{12} + \frac{6}{12} + \frac{4}{12} + \frac{3}{12} + \frac{2}{12} +\frac{1}{12} \\=\frac{12+6+4+3+2+1}{12}=\frac{28}{12} = \boxed{\frac{7}{3}}.\end{align*}

The answer is the sum of the divisors of 12 divided by 12, why is that?

Comment: This is because $\sigma(12)=1+2+3+4+6+12=28$ is the sum of the divisors of $12$.

Comment: Is any of the four steps unclear? $12+6+4+3+2+1$ is the sum of the divisors of $12$ because the divisors of $12$ are $12, 6, 4, 3, 2, 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it's true "for all values of $12$".

The point is this.  The sum of $1/d$ for all divisors of $n$ is the sum of $(n/d)/n$.
But the numbers $n/d$ are again the divisors of $n$, i.e. the positive integer $d$ divides $n$ if and only
if there is a positive integer $y$ such that $dy=n$, and then $y=n/d$ is again a divisor of $n$. So

$$ \sum_{d \mid n} \frac{1}{d} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{d \mid n} d $$

Comment: “For all values of 12”. Ha ha

Comment: At least for now,I'm not advanced enough to understand this answer, anyway, thank you